# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240007 when querying Windows Updates

Tags: c#, windows, windows-update

I am getting the error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240007" when I am trying to fetch the installed Windows updates. My code worked well in Windows 7, but it's not working in Windows XP. I am getting the error in the line `var history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);`

This is my code snippet:

```
        var updateSession = new UpdateSession();
        var updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
        var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
        var history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);
```

What changes do I need to make in the code?

Answer (score 7):

0x80240007 is the error code WU_E_INVALIDINDEX as defined in wuerror.h:

```
// MessageId: WU_E_INVALIDINDEX
//
// MessageText:
//
// The index to a collection was invalid.
//
#define WU_E_INVALIDINDEX                _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80240007L)
```

And the call to `UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher.QueryHistory` boils down to [IUpdateSearcher::QueryHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its documentation says:

> Remarks
>
> This method returns WU_E_INVALIDINDEX if the startIndex parameter is less than 0 (zero) or if the Count parameter is less than or equal to 0 (zero).

`count` is most likely not less than 0 but maybe `==0`

You need something like

```
var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
var history = count > 0 ? updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count) : null;
```

(or a more complex case handling....)

Comment: thanks for the reply sir.. but I am not getting what changes do i need to make in the code above.

Comment: You have to check whether GetTotalHistoryCount() returns a "usable" value, i.e. `if ( count > 0 )`.

Comment: yes m getting the count zero. but there are windows updates installed in my machine. y is the count 0? Is it because its not able to fetch updates installed?